# How can i pass parameter for a method with 2-dimensional arrays like "doSomething(float[][] a)"

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

If I have a method

```
doSomething(float[][] a)
```

and want to pass parameter to this method from main,

What is the syntax for floats in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two common ways are as follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        doSomething(new float[][] {{1,2},{3,4}});
        float x[][]=new float[][] {{1,2},{3,4}};
        doSomething(x);
    }

    static void doSomething(float[][] a) {

    }
}
```